# Adding KmlLayer using local file (File API)

Tags: data, kml, google, url

I am trying to load a local KML file to the map for this I am using FileReader object (File API). To use google.maps.KmlLayer I need to use readAsDataURL to transform to a URL the file, the problem is that KML File is not loading to the map and I don't get any error. I think may be url attribute in KmlLayer doesn't accept data url.

This is the code:

```
gp.addEventListeners = function(){
  $("#file-upload").change(function (evt){
      var file  = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function () {
         var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: reader.result
        });
        ctaLayer.setMap(gp.map);
      }

      if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }     
  });
}
```

In OpenLayes the same code is working.

What I can do? I need help :(

Sorry for my English.

Comment: That can't possibly work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514785/loading-a-local-kml-file-using-google-maps for why and a possible solution.

Comment: @BradHards I think that post is different, I am not using localhost I tranforming the file to uri data scheme https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/data_URIs to use this URI in the URL attribute. Here there is more information how works readAsDataURL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL

Comment: Its the same basic issue - google needs to be able to read your KML file. It all happens on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

Save the file in server then get the fullpath of the file. Assign fullpath to KmlLayer constructor